# Amazon Lex fulfillmentActivity.codeHook

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am following this tutorial provided in the Amazon Lex documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/getting-started-ex2.html

and I am getting this error when I finally save my intent:
`The value ‘null’ specified for ‘fulfillmentActivity.codeHook.uri’ is invalid. Member must not be null`

If anyone can help me with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed this step when creating the intent: `Fulfillment – Leave Return parameters to client selected. We're not using a Lambda function in this example.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lambda functions with your bot then you must integrate it with your bot else just check the return parameters to client and that should work fine.